# Allow PUT in net 6 Web API

Tags: iis, webapi

I got errors from swagger , I tried google arround and youtube , but do not find problem , Any one help me out , thank you so much !

This is error message :

```
    
Error: Method Not Allowed

Response body
Download
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>
  <h3>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
Response headers
 allow: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,TRACE 
 content-length: 1293 
 content-type: text/html 
 date: Wed,27 Sep 2023 07:54:03 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

I want to IIS 10 allow PUT method.
This is my web.config :
[image: Webconfig]

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the WebDAVModule from iis by following below steps:

1. Open iis manager, select your website
2. Click "Modules" from middle pane
3. Select WebDAVModule, click remove from action pane.
4. Restart iis site

Add PUT for the site:

1. Open iis, select your site
2. Double click request filtering , go to the HTTP verb section
3. Click Allow verb from action pane
4. Enter PUT in the verb

[image]

Add custom header:

1. Go to your site, select HTTP Response header
2. Select Add from action pane
3. Enter below values:

Name:Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Value:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

[image]

Comment: I follow your guide , but still that error ! Can you check again ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @Gàcon could you share your web.config file?

Comment: I upload my web.config ! Can you review it ? Thank you

Comment: @Gàcon could you try this web.config code

Comment: <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
<remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\swaggertest.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location> <system.webServer>
        <security>    <requestFiltering>   <verbs>
                    <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />   </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>  </system.webServer>